# Phalcon 4.x creates multiple folders to store cached data. What is the benefit of having recursive and multiple folders?

Tags: recursion, caching, directory, phalcon

```php
$hash = '123456789';
$fileName = "test.{$hash}.html";
```

the final directory structure will be like following.

`te/st/.1/23/45/67/test.123456789.html`

it simply breaks down the file name in to directories of two characters leaving the last 2 chars from the path `test.123456789`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent `too many files in one folder` error. 
See https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/cache#stream as well.

Comment: Thank you, and what is the purpose of skipping least 2 chars in the file path?